# How to provide in-text citation for Appendix

Tags: thesis, masters, cross-referencing

My master's dissertation has been sent back to me for copy edits before publication. One of the comments from the editors is "please provide in-text citation for Appendix". Now, I haven't actually referenced the appendix anywhere in the paper, it's more just extra information that relates to the topic and some of my interviewees who provided field data. How shall I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to provide a reference to the Appendix (e.g., "for further details, see Appendix) wherever the additional information is relevant. If your Appendix contains several different types of content then subheadings would be helpful. Then, you can reference the specific Appendix sections in your text. Seeing as you're at the copyediting phase now, you likely don't have many other options.

Comment: Thank you, I have taken your advice. Makes sense. Very much appreciated.